Help verifying solution for this PDE
I'm working on solving the partial differential equation (PDE):
$$
YF_X + F_Y F_{XX} + F F_{XXY} - \dfrac{1}{2} F_{YY} = 0
$$
I proposed a solution of the form:
$$
F(X, Y) = a_0(X) + a_1(X) Y + a_2(X) Y^2
$$
where $a_0(X)$, $a_1(X)$, and $a_2(X)$ are functions to be determined.
Here's how I obtained the values of $a_0(X)$, $a_1(X)$, and $a_2(X)$:

Assuming $a_2(X)=c$:


Since the PDE involves second derivatives with respect to $Y$, I considered $a_2(X)$ to be constant to simplify the problem. This assumption leads to $a_2'(X) = 0$ and $a_2''(X) = 0$.


Finding $a_1(X)$:


I substituted $a_2(X)=c$ into the equations derived from the PDE (specifically, the coefficient of $Y^2$ terms).
This led to the ordinary differential equation (ODE):
$$
         a_1'(X) + 3 c a_1''(X) = 0
$$
Solving this ODE, I obtained:
$$
         a_1(X) = -3 c e^{ -\dfrac{X}{3 c} }
$$


Solving for $a_0(X)$:


Using $a_2(X)=c$ and $a_1(X)$ found above, I derived another ODE from the PDE (from the coefficient of $Y$ terms):
$$
         a_0''(X) + \left( \dfrac{ a_1''(X) }{ a_1(X) } \right ) a_0(X) = \dfrac{ c }{ a_1(X) }
$$
Substituting $a_1(X)$ and its derivatives, I solved this second-order linear ODE to find:
$$
         a_0(X) = C_1 \cos\left( \dfrac{X}{3 c} \right ) + C_2 \sin\left( \dfrac{X}{3 c} \right ) - \dfrac{3 c^2}{2} e^{ \dfrac{X}{3 c} }
$$
Here, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants of integration.

With these functions, I constructed $F(X, Y)$ as:
$
F(X, Y) = \left[ C_1 \cos\left( \dfrac{X}{3 c} \right ) + C_2 \sin\left( \dfrac{X}{3 c} \right ) - \dfrac{3 c^2}{2} e^{ \dfrac{X}{3 c} } \right ] + \left( -3 c e^{ -\dfrac{X}{3 c} } \right ) Y + c Y^2
$
I attempted to verify if this $F(X, Y)$ satisfies the PDE by computing the necessary derivatives and substituting them back into the equation.
Upon substitution, I grouped like terms and obtained expressions involving $Y^2$, $Y$, and constants. The $Y^2$ terms canceled out, and the constant terms summed to zero, which is consistent with the PDE.
However, I found that the terms involving $Y$ do not generally cancel out, suggesting that the PDE is not identically satisfied with this solution.
Could someone help me identify any mistakes in my computations or reasoning?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Does this come with a domain for $(X, Y)$ and any sort of boundary conditions? As it stands, $F = \text{constant}$ is a solution.

It is assumed that we’re thinking of its domain being all of $R^2$. Unfortunately, no conditions given.
